# How do I access a website blocked in my country?

Tags: networking, security, proxy, bypass

Last year there were numerous cyber attacks on Israeli banks, so they just blocked access to all foreign countries. Is there a way to bypass that? I tried using a proxy, but it didn't work out.

Comment: What didn't "work out" and why? Most likely you just need to try another proxy.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/), although the exit node IPs are easily obtainable and many filters block them by default.  Unfortunately you may not be able to bypass it unless you can make friends with someone in the allowed country and convince them to set up a proxy for you to use.  That would do it because the traffic would appear to be coming from the allowed country.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a SSH server in another country (where there is no filtering), you can make an SSH tunnel to it, set dynamic port forwarding to this server, encapsulate your traffic from your browser via socks5 proxy into the ssh tunnel and voila.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tor:
[This Answer on the Tor Stack Exchange has more details](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/850)

{IL} in the ExitNodes configuration should do what you want.